# Rig has simply... disappeared from the viewport

Tags: armature, rigify

So I was trying the transfer weight paint features and then I saved my file to do some stuff in zbrush and I come back 2 hours later and the rig simply... gone. It's still in the outliner and I can still select it and switch between rest mode and pose mode, and I can see the rigify buttons in the 'n' toolbar, but its just not in the 3d viewport. I've tried alt-h in pose mode, nothing happened. I honestly have no idea what to do now

Any help will be appreciated

Blend file(Possibly NSFW.. just a base mesh without clothes):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FTnG3JeckrukCOJA8pdZYgoBWdjPMhkR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should add a NSFW warning next time...Your *Widgets* collection is disabled for whatever reason.

Comment: My b.. Would that be the cause? Surely someones gotta have had this problem before. If I change the rig 'display as' to 'bounds' it shows the bounds in the viewport but thats about it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to Window > Previous workspace, then Window > Next workspace and now the rig is fully visible again